# Convert existing MySQL php app to firebase database

Tags: mysql, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

How can I convert my MySQL database to a Firebase database without rewriting the database? Is there a way of exporting to Firestore or Realtime database and I just change a few things in my PHP code?

I am still confused how I can have my app work remotely using free Firebase hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick primer for you:

1. Convert MySQL to Firebase:

- Export your MySQL database to JSON.
- Use Firebase Admin SDK to upload the JSON data.

```js
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://your-database-url.firebaseio.com"
});

let data = require('./yourExportedMySQLdata.json');
admin.database().ref().set(data);
```

2. Update PHP for Firebase:

- Replace MySQL queries with Firebase API calls using Firebase PHP SDK.

```php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;

$factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json');
$database = $factory->createDatabase();

$newPost = $database->getReference('path/in/database')->push([
    'title' => 'Post title',
    'body' => 'This is the post body'
]);
```

3. Firebase Hosting:

- Deploy your app on Firebase hosting.

```bash
firebase init hosting
firebase deploy
```

Note: Make sure you've replaced database operations in your PHP app with Firebase SDK calls before deploying.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a magic button that converts your MySQL database to Firestore or the Realtime Database, please note that there isn't one. So, you'll have to write code for the conversion yourself.

Comment: Wow, I get it now. I've read about this the whole day and I've got several recommendations like exporting my tables as JSON, though i think am going for AWS now. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Yes, you can export your tables to JSON and upload them to the Realtime Database or you can create a mechanism to write the data in Firestore.

Comment: Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: More information would be much appreciated @AlexMamo. Let me clearly define what I really want. I have a database system that I have designed in PHP and MySQL for local access. I already have a domain and used firebase hosting because its free. I want to continue using this advantage with my PHP-MySQL app. Which easier way do you suggest. I know firebase supports PHP, but I already have working data in my DB and i have to rewrite the CRUD for firebase.

Comment: If you want to benefit from the features Firebase provides, then you should consider transferring the data from the SQL database to Firestore or the Realtime Database. I don't think it will be that hard.

Comment: Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?